# What types can there be for "UDLText"s other than comments?

Tags: intersystems-cache

I am now using the Caché DB jar to query for class definitions (thanks [@daimor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1279493/daimor); it was an eye opener) and in order to write the source files I need to also account for "UDL texts".

Now, all I have been able to understand of them so far is that they are comments found in the source you actually write in Studio. But then `UDLTextDefinition` defines `.getCategory()`; the only value I have seen this method return so far is `"comment"`.

Is there any other possible value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open source code for that class (%Dictionary.UDLTextDefinition), you will find `CategoryIsValid` method, and will see, that only two values are correct now, and it is `comment` and `error`. I'm sure you understand category `comment`. So, `error` used when developer managed to save source code with syntax errors in class definition, and that text will be in UDLText and with category `error`.

Comment: Interesting... Err, do you happen to perform consulting on Intersystems Caché? :p

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I'm just developer in Caché, and mostly answering on russian [forum](http://www.sql.ru/forum/cache), it is now the biggest place in the world, where everybody can ask and get answer and where I am a moderator. Another place is [google groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/intersystems-public-cache), where I'm answering sometime. And here mostly for train my english. :)

Comment: Huh, I don't speak a word of Russian... Too bad, I'm sure I'd have been able to extract useful info from the forum otherwise... In any case, I can only admire your skills with Caché!

Comment: Interesting that, our forum have a "[mirror](http://www.progtown.com/forum20-databases.html)", if it possible to say so. That forum where somebody translate some topics from our forum in english, but we don't know who, and why he doing it.